# I am an American citizen freelancing in Germany. Can I keep my clients and move back to the US and work remotely?

Tags: freelance

I am an American citizen freelancing in Germany.  Can I keep my clients and move back to the US and work remotely?

Comment: Your question is pretty broad and I think more information is needed to be able to answer. What has your own research on this revealed? Are you asking about eg tax implications, employment laws, data protection?

Comment: Your place of work is where you are located as you are doing the work. You'll do the work in the US, so you're working in the US and as a citizen, this is allowed. Whether you have to make arrangements to carry on a business in Germany is an issue I'll leave for others to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what your clients wish.

- A German client, especially a small company, may be unwilling to go to the effort of hiring contractors from the US. Contracts get more complicated, taxes get more complicated, in case of disagreements lawsuits get more complicated. This may be overcome by mutual trust, or not.
- If you are working in information technology (and most remote-capable jobs touch IT matters), the client may be legally unable to transfer data from the EU to the US.